gaussian process classification, deriving posterior for label
Context
I'm currently studying classification using gaussian processes.
It's all described in https://gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW3.pdf.
I'm stuck with understanding and proving the probabilities 3.9 and 3.10 in there (this question will be focused on 3.10, another one has been asked specifically for 3.9).
The problem is modeled like this (if I got everything right):

$X$ are $N$ measures in $\mathbb{R}^D$
$Y$ are the $N$ corresponding
binary labels (at this stage, we're dealing with a simple 2 classes
problem).

Now it gets fuzzy. AFAIU:
$p\left(Y|X\right)=\sigma\left(f\left(X\right)\right)$ where $f$ is an unknown function $\mathbb{R}^D\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ and $\sigma$ a fixed, strictly increasing, bijective, function $\mathbb{R}\mapsto\left[0;1\right]$
$f$ is also named a latent variable (a hidden function of the measure that, hopefully, makes the classification process easier).
The label are said to be generated independently conditional on $f\left(x\right)$ but I'm not sure how to interpret it.
My assumption would be: $p\left(Y|f\left(X\right),X\right)=\prod_{i=1}^N p\left(y_i|f\left(x_i\right),x_i\right)$.
Now $f$ is unknown but it is modeled as having some regularity, using gaussian processes. Thus $f$ can be seen, a priori, as a random variable such that if $F$ are the $N$ values $f\left(x_i\right)$:
$p\left(F|X\right)=\mathcal{N}_F\left(\mu,K\left(X\right)\right)$
Where $\mathcal{N}_F$ denotes a multivariate normal law, with variable $F$, mean $\mu$ in $\mathbb{R}^N$ and $K\left(X\right)$ a definite positive matrix.
So the idea is that a measure $x$ and gives a probability $\sigma\left(f\left(x\right)\right)$ of having $y=+1$. But this probability is itself a random variable because f is here random and has only some regularity modeled as a gaussian process.
Now we want to go for a supervised classification, using observations $\{X,Y\}$ in order to get an estimate of $p\left(y_*|x_*,X,Y\right)$ for a new sample.
The issue in this situation is that the function $f$ that models $p\left(Y|X\right)$ is itself unknow and our knowledge of it only improves indirectly from accumulated observations.
label posterior
The second stage of this process results in the equation 3.10 in above reference:
$p\left(y_*|x_*,X,Y\right)=\int_{f_*}\sigma\left(f_*\right)p\left(f_*|x_*,X,Y\right)df_*$ 
This is the second equation I'd like to prove
Though it seems natural I'm failing to untangled $X\leftrightarrow Y\leftrightarrow F$ inter-dependencies correctly to reach this result.
I started by the obvious, going to $p\left(y_*,x_*,X,Y\right)$ with Bayes rule and then marginalizing: $p\left(y_*|x_*,X,Y\right)=\frac{\int_{F_*} p\left(y_*,f_*,x_*,X,Y\right)dF_*}{p\left(x_*,X,Y\right)}=\frac{\int_F p\left(y_*|x_*,f_*,X,Y\right)p\left(f_*,x_*,X,Y\right)dF_*}{p\left(x_*,X,Y\right)}=\int_F p\left(y_*|x_*,f_*,X,Y\right)p\left(f_*|x_*,X,Y\right)dF_*$
(using the additional hypothesis that the next sample point $x_*$ is independent from previous observations) but I don't know how I can get $X,Y$ to disappear, leaving only a condition on $x_*,X,f_*$

[IDEA] It would be trivial with the correct "conditional independence". ie if I can tell that $(x_*,y_*,f_*)$ and $Y$ are independent conditionally to $X$ but I don't know how to derive this property from the hypotheses.
